# Error bars calculation in a split-plot design

Tags: data-visualization, standard-deviation, standard-error, split-plot

I have the following experimental design :
Sampling is carried out on three random sites (Factor Site is coded : Site1, Site2, Site3).
Within each site, sampling is carried out in a dry plot and in a wet plot (Factor Hydrology is coded : Dry/Wet)
Within each of the previous plot, sampling is carried out at two Depths (D1, D2) in triplicate.
There are a total of n = 36 samples = 3 Sites * 2 Hydrology * 2 Depths * 3 Replicates.

I use the lme function in R (lnme package) as follows :

```
Site<-as.factor(rep(c("Site1","Site2","Site3"),each=12))
Hydrology<-as.factor(rep(rep(c("Dry","Wet"),each=6),3))
Depth<-as.factor(rep(rep(c("D1","D2"),each=3),6))
Variable<-rnorm(36)


mydata<-data.frame(Site,Hydrology,Depth,Variable)

mod1<-lme(Variable~ Hydrology*Depth, data=mydata, random=~1|Site/Hydrology/Depth)
```

I want to visualize the impact of Hydrology and Depth on the dependent variable without displaying the data for each Site :

```
interaction.HD<-interaction(mydata$Hydrology,mydata$Depth)
calculated_mean<-tapply(mydata$Variable,interaction.HD,mean)
mean_V=as.table(matrix(calculated_mean,nrow=2))
rownames(mean_V)=c("Wet","Dry")
colnames(mean_V)=c("D1","D2")

library(gplots)
graph=barplot2(mean_V, beside = TRUE)
legend("center",c("Dry","Wet"),pch=22,pt.bg = c("red","yellow"))
```

Each bar on the graph represents the mean of 9 values (3 replicates per Site for each combination of Hydrology and Depth).

I would like to plot error-bars on each mean. My question is the following : What is the most correct way to calculate it?

I think that it is incorrect to calculate the Standard-Deviation or the Standard-Error on the 9 values used to calculate each mean. 
I think it would be more correct to calculate SD or SE on 3 values (each value corresponding to the mean per site for each combination of Hydrology and Depth).

Any advice on this question would be much appreciated.

Do you think it is correct to use the method described in Cousineau (2005) where the between-subject variability is removed before the calculation of error bars? 
link to the reference : http://www.tqmp.org/Content/vol01-1/p042/p042.pdf

Comment: Any advice on this question?